# 32 bit IEEE floating point representation: exponent

Tags: ieee-754

If the magnitude of the number to be represented lies within the range 10^-200 to
10^+200, how many bit should be allocated to code the exponent?

It seems that it is already out of the range and it can't be represented. I am so confused, would anyone mind helping me?

Comment: Are you asking about the IEEE-754 floating point format, as the title indicates, or about floating point formats in general? IEEE-754 has eight bits of exponent; the numeric range is about 2^-126 to 2^127 (10^-38 to 10^38). To represent the range 10^-200 to 10^200 (about 2^-664 to 2^664) you would need 11 bits for the exponent.

Comment: It should be in general, thanks for helping me.

Comment: log_2 (1e+200) ≈ 664.38561897747246957406388589788. so you need 11 bits to represent 665*2 different values

Comment: @jlahd IEEE-754 defines several floating-point formats (7 in 2008 revision), not only single. IEEE-754 double precision/binary64 has exactly 11 bits of exponent

Comment: True, but the subject of the original post specifies "32 bit".